# How to calculate the miss rate of Data and Instruction Caches

Tags: caching, architecture, hardware, cpu-architecture

### The Situation

I'm trying to answer an architecture question on instruction and data caches I have found in a past exam paper (**not homework!**).

The question seems to give a lot of information which I haven't used in my solution. This makes me think I'm missing something and would be really grateful if someone could help me out!

### The (Full) Question

This is the full question as asked in the paper. For a summary of key points please see below.

> Calculate the miss rate for a machine S with separate instruction
>   cache and data cache, each of n bytes. There are `I` misses per `K`
>   instructions for the instruction cache, and d misses per k
>   instructions for the data cache.
>
> A fraction `X` of instructions involve data transfer, while a fraction
>   `Y` of instructions contain instruction references, the rest contain
>   data references. A hit takes `H` cycles and the miss penalty is `M`
>   cycles.

### Key Question Points

**Given**:

- Data and instruction caches are separate
- Each cache has **`N`** bytes
- **`I`** misses per **`K`** instructions for instruction cache
- **`D`** misses per **`K`** instructions for the data cache
- A fraction **`X`** of the instructions involve **data transfer**
- A fraction **`Y`** of the instructions involve **instruction references**
- The rest of the instructions contain **instruction references**
- A hit takes **`H`** cycles
- The miss penalty is **`M`** cycles

**Calculate**: Miss Rate of Machine

### Attempts so far

I originally thought that the miss rate would be `(I/K)*Y + (D/K)*(1 - X - Y)` but since this doesn't use all the data provided, I don't think it can be right :(.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Is there any clarification in the paper about _data transfer_ and _data references_? They look very similar to me. Btw, there is an inconsistency between the text of the question and your key question points: "a fraction Y of instructions contains instruction references" (question) vs. "a fraction Y of instructions involve data references". I assume the correct version is the one in the key points, right?

Comment: Hi, no, the full question was right. I have now amended the question. I don't believe I ever actually managed to answer it, so will leave it up here for now.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you maybe interpreting the question wrong or the question is not well framed. Miss rate of cache is obviously `no. of misses/total no. of accesses`. The only thing I can think of which uses all the info of the question is calculating the miss penalty for a cache miss

Answer (score -1):

Hit timeL1 + Miss rateL1 * (Hit timeL2 + Miss rateL2 * Miss penatlyL2)